# How to utilize redirect location attribute in header using HttpResponse method of Django

Tags: python, django

I am using oauthlib, and I came across the following step

```
headers, body, status = grant.create_authorization_response(request, token)
```

When I print headers, body, status, then getting the following

```
headers = {u'Location': u'http://127.0.0.1:9998/grant_permission?code=RdWhPtXohTv3q47DNrpP
1vSL7IFmvU'} 

body = None 

status = 302
```

How do I pass these 3 variables to a HttpResponse method of Django, please let me know

I tried the following, but sill not getting redirected

```
response = HttpResponse(content=body)
response.status_code = status
for k, v in headers.items():
    print k," = ",v
    response[k] = v

return response
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the response body you must specify it on the object initialization passing it as the first argument of the constructor method.

For setting headers and response status code, from the Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/):

> HttpResponse.status_code : The HTTP status code for the response

That is, you set status code as an object attribute.

> To set or remove a header field in your response, treat it like a
>   dictionary

If you need to redirect to a different url use the object HttpResponseRedirect specifying the url in the object constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I edited the question. could you please verify the above code

Comment: if you need to redirect to the new location use the object HttpResponseRedirect specifying the location at object initialization.

Answer (score 0):

The `Location` should be in the headers, not the response body. The following should work.

```
from django import HttpResponse

headers, body, status = grant.create_authorization_response(request, token)
response = HttpResponse(status=status)
response['Location'] = headers['location']
return response
```

However, in Django, you would usually redirect using [`HttpResponseRedirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect). This takes care of setting the headers, and returns a response with status code 302 (temporary redirect).

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

headers, body, status = grant.create_authorization_response(request, token)
location = headers['Location']
return HttpResponseRedirect(location)
```